# Facebook like button in Rails, how to put Facebook JS in assets?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook-like, assets

I am doing this in order to have Facebook like button in my page:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

And after that:

```
<fb:like href= "" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

This works well.  But instead of having to connect to **Facebook** to get the **all.js**
file, I would like to have that content statically in my assets. So.. I tried getting the content of that file, and putting it in a js file that is loaded in the page..

However, the button is not loading when I do that. Am I missing something? If it's not possible to get the all.js, I believe I could cache that right?

Comment: I'd assume that Facebook takes every measure to cache things right. Do you experience any problems with it?

Comment: Not yet. I am just assuming they want you to cache because in their docs page it says "recommendation of adding a channel file", but the snippet is in PHP, and I am not really sure how to do it in Rails. Take a look if you want: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ -- look for channel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel file is a file that contains this script directive. It is not the script itself. You need the channel file to help cross-domain communication in some browsers. Since channel file never changes, it is good thing to cache it right. The javascript, on the other hand, might change at some point (thing change, API evolves, etc), so you don't need to aggressively cache it. Let Facebook do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have the doubt if I should create the channel file or not.

Comment: How would I create that file? Where should I place it? Which content should I put in it?

Comment: @HommerSmith: it's right there in the docs. Look for channel file :)

Comment: Thank you Sergio, and I like a lot your blog.